# Proof of RAP-derivation sequence for a set of functional dependencies in relational databases

Tags: proof-techniques, database-theory, databases, relational-algebra

I'm reading David Maier's outstanding but out-of-print book on relational databases (the book,"The Theory of Relational Databases", is available online from the author's website http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~maier/TheoryBook/TRD.html). I have a question regarding the proof of Theorem 4.2 of Chapter 4. On page 55 of the book (see pdf for Chapter 4 if you don't have the book), it was said that the FDs of step 13 and 14 can be replaced by new steps 13.1 ... 13.k and 14 that follows. It seems to me that only step 13.k is needed and steps 13.1 - 13.(k-1) are unnecessary. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here, but the author didn't explain. In fact, the example in the proof shows that only step 13.k is used.

Comment: Could you cite the needed parts? We prefer questions to be self contained, also the website might be down at any time. In such case the question gets unanswerable. There are a lot of pdfs, pages that you provide are probably the book pages, not pdf pages, but your chances to get answer increase when we do not have to jump between several pdfs to understand to track your thoughts.

Comment: It's hard to make the question self-contained. The proof spans two full pages. But you only need Chapter 4, which is in one pdf file, so there's no need to jump around between pdfs files. The pdfs have been posted there for a long time (many years now) and, I believe, will continue to stay there (the book is out-of-print and so I think the author's intention is to make it accessible. The book is his most cited work.)